# Failing to force the link error of a static member variable happen

Tags: c++

**Please DO NOT make my question as a duplicate. I wanted to force the error to happen!!!! I am not asking how to solve the error. Thank you.**

I've heard that if a static member variable is initialised in a header file, and if the header file is included in many different source files, then a link error will occur. And I do believe that.

However, I failed to force the error happen. My program can always be complied successfully. Some say that the include guards prevent the error. It still worked even if I got rid of the include guards.

**s1.h**

```
#ifndef S1_H
#define S1_H

class S
{
public:
    S();
    static int num; // just make it public so that it can be used
};

int S::num = 10;

#endif // S1_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "s1.h"

#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    qDebug() << S::num;
}
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "s1.h"

#include <QtDebug>

class Test
{
public:
    Test();
    void printNum() {qDebug() << S::num;}
};
```

Comment: Here we go: [**Live Demo on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/h5Wix50iXQgm48Nb). This happens if the definition occurs in more than one translation unit AND you try to link the corresponding object files together. THEN the ODR (one definition rule) is violated.

Comment: @scheff - Must say I haven't considered the OP not linking their program properly. Seems a likely culprit here.

Comment: How are you compiling this? Are you sure test.cpp is actually being built? What compiler and build system are you using?

Comment: @Scheff  that's weird but it always works on my machine using Qt creator with MSVC 2017 64bit.

Comment: @StoryTeller I was under impression that OP want's to see how the violation looks. Hence, I tried to demonstrate this (IMHO successfully). ;-) Writing the definition into the header, isn't actually the violation of ODR. However, a header is usually intended to be used in multiple sources which are linked together. So, definition in header is the "root" of evil which will likely happen later...

Comment: @BrennanVincent I run the program then the console came out and told me it's 10

Comment: Please, note, that one of the changes in my example was to USE class test in `main()` (i.e. make an instance and call `Test::printNum()`). Not that the linker ignores contents of test.cpp because it's nowhere used. (I'm not quite sure whether this might hide the ODR violation...)

Comment: But are you sure both objects are linked into the final executable? This is key here.

Comment: @Scheff oh I got it now

Comment: @StoryTeller I think that's the point, I finally noticed that

Comment: This should definitely cause a multiple definition linker error.

Comment: Off topic. Not able to commrnt on the question so I write here.
MSVC17 toolset 141 has a bug for `inline static` members causing to instantiate the same object/variable couple times (one per TU).